# Webpack 4 library to display mathml in a webpage?

Tags: firefox, webpack, webkit, webpack-4, mathml

I'm attempting to use some javascript for webpack 4 to display an equation in Firefox 62 (and eventually I hope to make it work on webkit). I was using [this](https://webkit.org/demos/mathml/demo2016/) as my example (maybe it was a mistake to use a webkit example for a test in Firefox...though by now I thought it would render the same)

I've used the Javascript in it to create the following content in side my page to display a simple **a<sup>2</sup>**, but it's displaying **a2** instead:

```
<body>
...
<math display="block">
   <semantics>
      <mrow>
        <msup>
           <mi>a</mi>
           <mn>2</mn>
        </msup>
      </mrow>
   </semantics>
</math>
```

...

This there some reason this isn't working?

Comment: Chrome [doesn't natively support MathML](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5240822173794304), so a library like [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/#gettingstarted) has to be used. What method are you using to generate that markup?

Comment: I'm using Javascript DOM methods like `createElement()` and `appendChild()`